# What is DBase? How to use DBase in Win98 Operating system?

Tags: database, dbase

**What is DBase?** How to use DBase in **Windows 98**? How to install **DBase**?

Comment: There are 82 references to the SO tag for the historically-quite-significant-dBase, which was a unique computer language and the first μ-processor data base. Perhaps we should not close this question just yet . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***What is dBase?***

A very early PC non-SQL (not exactly *"NoSQL"*) relational database.

***How do I use DBase in Windows 98?***

dBase was a breakthrough product, the first μ-processor DB, and for that matter a primitive predecessor of important tools like Perl, but it was later eclipsed by clones and then by various SQL products.

If I wanted something similar today I would just use Ruby, ActiveRecord, and MySQL.

***How do I install DBase?***

But if you want the real thing, and something that will run on Win98 (gods, but why?) I would look up [dBASE on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBASE) and see if the downstream products like FoxPro and Clipper are available. See also [dBase, LLC.](http://www.dbasellc.com/)

Also note that many of today's quite powerful DBMS packages can read dbf files.

Comment: I think MS still ships Visual FoxPro with certain MSDN subscriptions, along with Win 98, VB6 and other software that we hope to never see again :-) How close that actually is to Ashton Tate's dBase II/III I have no idea.

Comment: I believe they discontinued FoxPro development recently, but sure, it seems reasonable that they would ship the still-current latest (and very last) version.

Comment: Hi Ross, Which is light weight database among all the databases we have and Which is opensource. Kindly help to me Mr.Ross